# gitosis: configuration does not exist

Tags: linux, git, gitosis

Gitosis does not update my authorized_keys and therefore I'm not able to create new users in git. post-update under gitosis-admin.git is executable. I tried then to run the script manually on the server (sudo -u gitosis sh ./post-update), which ends in the following error:

```
ERROR:gitosis.app:Configuration does not exist: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.gitosis.conf'
```

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't have to update autorized_keys. Communication is done over one id and identification is done via what public key is subsequently submitted - but at that point ssh is already satisfied.

You should switch to gitolite anyway. Gitosis is no longer being actively developed.

Comment: Gitosis authorizes connections as its UID and subsequently determines who is making the connection by putting users' keys in `authorized_keys`. That said, this answer is right that you should really just use Gitolite.